# OUTPUT Clause value with another Data in SQL Sever : C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using below query to get OUTPUT Clause value with another data.

```
@PageIndex bigint=1,
@PageSize bigint=5,
@RecordCount bigint=0 OUTPUT,

Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpId ASC) AS RowNumber, 
        EmpId, 
        (Salutation + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as Name, 
        Specialties, 
        EmpPhoto 
INTO #Results 
from tblEmployee 
Where EmpType='Doctor'

Select @RecordCount = COUNT(*) from #Results

Select * 
from #Results 
Where RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 
AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

DROP TABLE #Results
```

Now, I want `@RecordCount` value with another data of `Select` query. How to get it in C# ? I am using 3-tier architecture so I have created method with `DataTable` datatype. So, what changes I will need to do ?

Comment: Your title is misleading. It should be "How to retrieve SQL data in C#?" To which there are a multitude of options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// 1. Create the output parameter
var p = new SqlParameter("RecordCount", 0) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

// 2. Make the SQL call
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Retrieve reader values from query
    }
}

// 3. Retrieve the value of the output parameter
var recordCount = (long)p;
```

Another option would be to refactor your SQL and do

```
RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
```

Which can be retrieved in C# with the following (note that you are limited to an `int` type for the return value)

```
cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"]
```

And as an aside, avoid using TempDb like that. It's unnecessary. And a better way to page is like this using built-in SQL paging

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
OFFSET (@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Yes, right. But then hw will i get value of Select query ?

Comment: I got idea from your code and i have solved my issue. Thank you... :)

Comment: @Didaxis `RETURN @@ROWCOUNT` will return number of rows affected by last `select` and it is not the same as in original question. Originally @Records count was count of records under some condition, and resultset selected was some smaller subset of it. I don't know was it intended or not, but it differs from your solution.

Comment: @Andy, you are absolultely correct based on his original SQL statements. I did say if he'd refactor the code then he could use `@@ROWCOUNT` but I probably should've clarified that a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't show your c# code - it is hard to say what **changes** should you made.

But basically - you can't use `output` keyword in a script. It should be output parameter of **stored procedure** - so you have to wrap your logic into stored procedure and call it from c# code.

In this case you should add parameter to your SqlCommand with `ParameterDirection.Output`. After executing command you can get returned value of your parameter from `SqlParameter.Value` property.

Comment: Yes, right. But then hw will i get value of Select query ?

Comment: @JeetenParmar you will get that data from select query in the same manner you're doing it right now. It can be many possible ways - using SqlDataReader, SqlDataAdapter and so on - I don't know what are you using. The essential change - is wrapping logic into stored procedure and calling this procedure providing parameter with type = output. Method of getting data into DataTable or DataSet not changes at all.